# Deleted revisions still listed

Tags: views, 8

I started dev on Drupal 8.6.0 and have since updated to 8.6.3. I have also cleared caches, run updates and cron.

I have set up a content revisions view:

FIELDS
Content revision: Revision create time
Content revision: Revision ID
Content revision: ID

FILTER CRITERIA
Content revision: Published (= Yes)

SORT CRITERIA
Content revision: Revision create time (desc)

CONTEXTUAL FILTERS:
Content revision: ID

So I can get all the revisions for 'this' node. The view is a block, so when I place the block on a node, I get the revision id & date showing as expected.

BUT, there seem to be additional revisions in the view then listed in the revisions tab.

For my test node, I have deleted some of the revisions.
The node's revisions tab lists:
revision id:97 - 21 Nov 2018 [the current active revision]
revision id:96 - 16 Nov 2018
revision id:39 - 22 Oct 2018
...

But the view is listing 
revision id:97 - 21 Nov 2018
revision id:96 - 16 Nov 2018
revision id:84 - 05 Nov 2018 <- not listed on the node's revisions tab

If I take a look at the DB, I have the following:

table: node
nid:1; vid: 97;
which matches the current node / vid

table: node_field_revision
nid:1; vid: 97; changed: 21 Nov 2018
nid:1; vid: 96; changed: 21 Nov 2018
nid:1; vid: 84; changed: 05 Nov 2018 <- not listed on the node's revisions tab
...

table: node_revision
nid:1; vid: 97; time 21 Nov 2018
nid:1; vid: 96; time 16 Nov 2018
nid:1; vid: 84; time 05 Nov 2018 <- not listed on the node's revisions tab
...

If I go to /node/1/revisions/84/view the revision shows.

How do I either remove these deleted revisions or filter them out of my view?

thank you for your help,

ice70

Answer (score 0):

I am using the diff module, pulled that apart to find it is using:

```
if ($revision-&gt;hasTranslation($langcode) &amp;&amp; $revision->getTranslation($langcode)-&gt;isRevisionTranslationAffected())
```

modified my view to use the filter:

Content revision: Revision translation affected (= True)

The revisions pulled by the view now match the revisions shown on the node's revisions tab.